# how to get the current location of the captured images in android and sending it?

Tags: eclipse

pls let me know the cade for getting the current location of images that is captured and sending to the selected persons
thank's in advance

Comment: You should re-tag this question - this is nothing to do with Eclipse.  Use one of the android tags, such as android-sdk.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the images from the camera are stored in /sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA

To access the camera directly, use the Camera class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html